List all Profiles Missing from Import in SharePoint Online?
How can I list or export all profiles marked as "-DELETED-guid" in Profile manager (ProfMngr.aspx) in SharePoint Online?
In SP On-Premise, you could access database, but it is impossible in online. Is there an API call or other technique that can achieve this?

You can do it with CSOM as Amy posted, but the easiest way is probably with PnP:
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -Interactive

$profiles = Get-PnPUserProfileProperty -Key "AccountName"

$deletedProfiles = $profiles | Where-Object { $_.AccountName -like "*-DELETED-*" }

$deletedProfiles | Export-Csv -Path "C:\deleted_profiles.csv" -NoTypeInformation


To make it, you can try PowerShell, for your reference:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/08/sharepoint-online-export-user-profile-properties-to-csv-using-powershell.html
